# RabbitMQ tools: rabbitmqctl vs rabbitmqadmin

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I'm new to RabbitMQ and I decided to start with console tools for better management understanding. Then I'm going to use web console and then Java client.

I faced some operations can be executed both with `rabbitmqctl`:

```
rabbitmqctl add_vhost test_vhost
```

and with `rabbitmqadmin`:

```
rabbitmqadmin declare vhost name="test_vhost"
```

But I did not succeed in, for instance, creating new exchange with rabbitmqctl. What's the difference between these two tools?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `rabbitmqctl` is native command line tool written in Erlang, in general, it is used inside the same server where RabbitMQ is running.
- `rabbitmqadmin` is a Python interface for the [HTTP management UI](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_11/priv/www/api/index.html). You cannot use it if management UI plugin is not installed.

There is an overlap between the two tools, but there are a few features that you can use only with one of them.

With `rabbitmqctl` you can:

- manage the rabbitmq clustuer, by adding/removing nodes.
- reset the node
- handle logs files rotation
- stop the node

`rabbitmqadmin` is more for general admin, you have the same features you have in the management UI, you can also retrieve the node statistics.